# Golang upgrading incompatible modules

Tags: go, go-modules

So I have a version of chi module that is incompatible and I can't upgrade it using `go get <package-name>` it only upgrades to the latest incompatible version while there are quite a few more versions released. I need some functionalities from the new version library which the incompatible one does not have. The go.mod file incompatible library looks like this:
`github.com/go-chi/chi v4.0.2+incompatible h1:maB6vn6FqCxrpz4FqWdh4+lwpyZIQS7YEAUcHlgXVRs=`

I tried deleting my modules and running go mod init again using, but it still gives me the incompatible version. I think this might be because my project is connected to my bitbucket repository. I also tried deleting the module from the go environment and downloading it again, but had the same outcome.

How can I overcome this problem? Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe I have to manually clear the modules from my repository as well and then try to init them again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the version you want starts to get compatible with Go modules, you have to `go get` the dependency and import the packages in source files with the correct versioned import path, as declared in *their* `go.mod` file.

Chi's current `go.mod` on master branch declares its module as:

```
module github.com/go-chi/chi/v5
```

So:

`go get github.com/go-chi/chi/v5`

And in source files:

```
import "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    // ...
}
```